# Key Management Interoperable Protocol

Tags: key-management, kmip

```
 When we say "KMIP is an interoperable protocol", 
 what does this really mean ? Please explain in this context only.
```

I know the meaning of interoperable.

Answer (score 1):

As the use of cryptographic techniques increased, it is complicated by inconsistencies and duplication in the key management systems supporting the devices. Each device has its own key management system. Different customers use different Key Lifecycle Management Systems (KLMS). Each of these KLMS works on their own protocol to communicate. KMIP establishes a single, comprehensive protocol for communication between enterprise key management servers and cryptographic clients. It addresses the need for a comprehensive key management protocol and hence it is called as "interoperable".

This helps in reducing operational and infrastructure costs